# Analyzing a query plan for a query with TWO predicates, but index only has ONE

Tags: mysql, optimization, execution-plan, database-theory

**Note**: This is from an introductory database systems course at my university so I'm not entirely sure if it matters, but for what it's worth we are being taught MySQL.

---

One homework question I'm doing right now is to analyze some query plans for a query with two predicates, specifically:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE wam > 75 AND faculty = 'Arts';
```

however the plans provided assume an index only on one of the predicates, such as an unclustered B+ tree index on (wam).

One example part of the question is as follows:

> Compute the estimated cost of the best plan assuming that an
>   unclustered B+ tree index on (wam) is the only index available.
>   Suppose there are 60 index pages. Discuss and calculate alternative
>   plans

How would I go about calculating the cost of a plan like this? Would I have to calculate costs for unclustered/clustered B+ tree and hash indexes for the other predicate, faculty, as well? I am aware that one alternative plan is also simply a full table scan.

"Student" has 800 pages, 64000 tuples. "faculty" can take 10 unique values. "wam" can take 100 unique values.

Thank you, if I'm not being specific enough feel free to point out anything lacking in this post.

Answer (score 2):

The optimal index for *that* query is `INDEX(faculty, wam)`, in *that order*.

MySQL does not (in most situations) use two different indexes.  However, it will use a 'composite' index to good use in some situations, such as this.

Without knowing how many rows have `Arts` and home many have `> 75`, you cannot accurately conclude which of `INDEX(wam)` or `INDEX(faculty)` would be better.  Nor can the Optimizer, since it's statistics gathering is not very good.  `SHOW INDEXES` and `EXPLAIN SELECT` provide numbers that come from the same statistics, so you won't necessarily come to the optimal conclusion.

A "Hash" index (which InnoDB does not have) is essentially no better than a BTree index.  A Hash index is useless for a range (eg, `> 75`).  (Hence, MySQL uses BTrees, and does not provide Hash indexes.)

Another point:  If more than a small percentage of the table has `wam > 75`, `INDEX(wam)` will be shunned; scanning the entire table is likely to be faster than bouncing between the index's BTree and the data BTree.  Again `> 75` and `60 pages` and `10` and `100` give no *good* clues of which path the Optimizer should take.  The answer to the quoted question is "it depends" or "not enough info".

You could tackle the question by presenting two answers:  One where very few rows have `wam > 75`, and one where most meet that predicate.

Has your instructor had any experience using databases, or only textbooks?

More discussion on devising optimal indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: "Nor can the Optimizer, since it's statistics gathering is not very good." I have to disagree (a bit), atleast since MySQL 8 is it possible to make histogram statistics with [ANALYZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html) for better statistics gathering still it would require to completly sample the table for the best results..  But still pretty useless if you don't have enough RAM to sample large tables, MySQL devs should really extend this feature that ram to ssd swapping can be used :-)

Comment: @RaymondNijland - Good points.  However, I doubt if the histogram generator really wants to fill up RAM.  And the Histogram is done once, not every time the query is run, correct?  Therefore, the cost of making it is not relevant.

Comment: *"However, I doubt if the histogram generator really wants to fill up RAM. And the Histogram is done once, not every time the query is run, correct?"*  Correct.. But the size of the "sample" is controled by [histogram_generation_max_mem_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_histogram_generation_max_mem_size) meaning to less RAM meaning your are not able to 100% scan the table if the table is larger then that setting..

Comment: *"Therefore, the cost of making it is not relevant."* Indeed that is right i was talking about adding a ssd swap so MySQL could fully sample tables larger then the histogram_generation_max_mem_size  setting..

Comment: I hope (but do not know for a fact) that the Histogram generator does not try to keep all the data in RAM.  One rarely needs a histogram with more than a hundred items.  The _entire_ table could be sorted (on disk), then probed to generate the buckets.  That setting implies to me that they may have not worked hard enough on the algorithm.

Comment: *"I hope (but do not know for a fact) that the Histogram generator does not try to keep all the data in RAM. "* If the estimated amount of data to be read into memory for histogram generation exceeds the limit defined by histogram_generation_max_mem_size, MySQL samples the data rather than reading all of it into memory. Sampling is evenly distributed over the entire table. MySQL uses SYSTEM sampling, which is a page-level sampling method. -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html.. So not very usefull if you defined 1 Gb histogram_generation_max_mem_size on a 100 Gb table

Comment: *" That setting implies to me that they may have not worked hard enough on the algorithm."* Indeed it has room for improvements .. As from the looks of it how the manual explains it if you define 2Gb histogram_generation_max_mem_size, MySQL might use up 2Gb RAM if the estimated amount is 1999 Mb for example ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland - Thanks for the link.